# How to filter months in chronological order?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you filter months in `mmm` format in calendar month order and not alphabetical?

When I do it April as "APR" will be before January as "JAN" for example that is not correct.

(I know that `Data > Sort > Custom` will do it but I want filter to succeed).

I have also tried customising the data e.g. by shortening `mmm-yy` to `mmm` and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This uses *AutoFilter*.  Say we start with:

[image]

The first step is to format as *"mmm"*

[image]

When we apply the *AutoFilter:*

[image]

We then click of the "Oldest to Newest" option and the result is:

[image]

Which is in date order rather than alphabetic order.